# How to use derived columns in Laravel DB query

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I'm having a bit of trouble with a query I'm trying to set up in my Laravel app.
I'm trying to calculate something on the database level and then return that to the user through an ajax call.

Here is a part of the function being called:

```
$query = \DB::table('db_table');

    switch ($request['type']) {
        case 'type1':
            $settingValue = $request['type1'];
            $query = $query->selectRaw('price - cost_price AS margin');
            $query = $query->havingRaw('margin < ?', [$settingValue]);

            break;

        case 'type2':
            $settingValue = $request['type2'];
            $query = $this->addSelectQuery($query, '((price - cost_price) / price) AS profit');
            $query = $query->havingRaw('profit < ?', [$settingValue]);

            break;

        default: 
            return false;
    }

    $filteredProducts = $query->where('id', '=', $id)->count();
```

I have already tried where, whereRaw and having but I keep getting the same error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException:
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "margin" does not exist
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "db_table" where "id" = 21 having margin < 15)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your`$query = $query->selectRaw('price - cost_price AS margin')` line, should this be `sum(price - cost_price) AS margin`?

Comment: No this should be calculated for every record and then the query should only retrieve the records amount of records that have a margin lower than the number the client filled in elsewhere on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the values in the `WHERE` clause:

```php
case 'type1':
    $settingValue = $request['type1'];
    $query->whereRaw('price - cost_price < ?', [$settingValue]);
    break;
```

Comment: Yes this appeared to have done the trick. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using the count() method which will not utilize your selectRaw.

Instead, add the count to your select and then fetch the count with value(), something like:

```
 $query->selectRaw('count(*) as count, price - cost_price AS margin')
       ->havingRaw('margin < ?', [$settingValue])
       ->value('count');
```